# CiviCRM Import contacts only adding some to groups

Tags: import, groups

I have to csv files with organisation contacts in them, when I import a group of contacts it says it has created all the contacts, but will only add 300/350 or 160/240 into the group.

I receive no errors during the process.

Is there something I can do to fix this as soon I may need to add large amounts of contacts this way.

Comment: Thanks for your question!  We'll need a lot more information before we can provide any useful advice though.  Could you please post your CiviCRM version and CMS + CMS version?  Also, could you say more about your hosting environment?  Do you have a local copy of the site to test with?  Usually these sorts of issues are related to restrictions from your webhost, it'd be good to test the issue on a local computer.